# I always get the 429 status when making google queries through Python via proxy

Tags: python, web-scraping, proxy, python-requests, http-status-code-429

I am using the requests library to make google queries.

```
url='https://google.com/search?hl=en&q='
request_result = requests.get(url+query, headers=headers,proxies=proxies)
```

I always get the 429 status, when I make a request via proxy. I have tried several proxies, free ones as well as one that is paid and has a dynamically changing IP.

Does this mean that somebody else has made requests via these proxies or is there something I can do to make ti work. If I run through my IP it works fine.

Comment: Proxies - free or paid - are generally very unreliable. Some even specifically state that they do not work with google (not stating it does not mean that they are guaranteed to work with google though). It is probably that the proxies you are using are either over-used or blocked by google.

Comment: That is my Suspicion as well. Do you know is their other avenue to explore to make them work, I know the 429 returns a Re-captcha.

Comment: There are purportedly ways to bypass certain captchas. I haven't tried any myself, but I think they rely on frameworks like selenium or requests_html

Comment: There is one thing though, I can use google in my browser if I set the proxy in my windows setting.

Comment: If you are 100% sure that your browser is using the proxy (i.e. if you google "what is my ip" and it shows the proxy ip), it might have something to do with requests, try using selenium or requests_html with the proxies and see what happens.

Comment: Your browser is probably sending google some cookies. 429 means "too many requests", so yes those proxies are no good.

Comment: On the other hand just sending a request throught witho no proxy works as well and I have tried it with Selenium as well.